# OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".body"}

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm doing automated testing. Here I am testing a MODAL. In visual studio it displays an error. I'm using C# programming language

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".body"}
```

How to handle this modal? This modal will not trigger with button. The trigger is JavaScript onload where the modal will auto display after login.

[image]

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("body")));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("modal-open")));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlUld.png)

this image from inspect element

Comment: I think you should use expected conditions, wait until appearance of modal and then run the test code, if it does not appear raise error or skip.

Comment: that doesn't look like a frame at all... probably just a DIV.  Your locator is targeting a class (css-style) named "body", which doesn't exist.

Comment: i've done try using css selector without switch frame, but still not detected by selenium. because this modal using DOM javascript. fflexible

Comment: right-click on the modal and choose, "inspect".  Copy/paste the HTML markup of that element into your post.